# How to run graphics on winGHCi?

Tags: haskell

I tried to run graphics (like Graphics.Gloss) on winGHCi, everytime it just froze my winGHCi and I have to restart it. It is even the same if I use "ghc --make" to make the source code and run it.

Is there any way to get graphics running on winGHCi?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you get it working with regular ghci? By compiling the source and running the binary? With `runghc`?

Comment: Works for me, kinda, under WinGhci 1.02 and ghci 7.0.3 (via Haskell Platform 2001.2.0.1) under Win7.  I say kinda because it runs fine, but doesn't exit cleanly and I also have to restart winghci.  Also, the window comes up behind the winghci window, might look for another window, with an OpenGL icon.  I see there's a new Haskell Platform RC out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm... the Gloss website suggest either updating to GHC 7.2, or installing Gloss with `cabal install gloss --flags="GLFW -GLUT"`. Try one of these.